# Getting a base class pointer (parent) in a base-derived (child) class object?

Tags: c++

So I have this class (the parent) that creates a dialog box and fills it with controls. Within that class is another class (the child) that creates a timer that links/passes a function call to an event system to update the contents of some of the controls at regular intervals. The problem comes from the timer update function needing to know the objects it needs to update.

I would like to simply pass the pointer of the base class to the child some how in a way that it's all self contained. But I can't figure out a way to make that happen. Anyone have any ideas?

I've searched for answers but all I got was accessing variables from inside the base class from within the child class. That would work but it seems unnecessary to fire an event for every individual control... (I guess I could create all the controls in an structure but that seems unnecessary)

the nested classes look a bit like this:

```
class CreateDialog{
    class timer{
    }
}
```

Comment: "*Within that class is another class (the child)*" Are you implying inheritance or composition here? Your question is confusing without at least some pseudo-code.

Comment: I added a quick sample of the code structure for you.

Comment: Ah, so a _nested_ class.. There is no parent or child here. :-] Why not just have `timer` take a pointer or reference to its owning `CreateDialog`?

Comment: Well I was hoping to do it all internally to be neat and tidy.

Comment: The fact that `timer` is inside of `CreateDialog` only changes `timer`'s scope -- it does not magically give `timer` any unusual access to `CreateDialog`, and _especially_ not to a certain instance of `CreateDialog`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to declare a static member variable in the parent class and set it to the pointer of parent within the constructor of parent class.

Comment: That sounds like it's asking for trouble. What happens if you have more than one instance of the class?

Comment: That might work actually, as the pointer variable would get stored in each base class created... I'll give it a try.